# Do "to ravel" and to "to unravel" mean the same thing?

Tags: negation

I'm reading [this dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel) for "ravel":

> transitive verb
>   1 a : to separate or undo the texture of : unravel 
>   b : to undo the intricacies of : disentangle
>
> intransitive verb
>   1 obsolete : to become entangled or confused 
>   2 : to become unwoven, untwisted, or unwound : fray
>   :3  break up, crumble

Some of these seem very similar to the meaning of "unravel" - ostensibly its opposite. Why is that?

Comment: Yes. Same thing with *raze*, with *cleave*, and so forth. Does a *pitted* olive have a pit, or was its pit removed? If something is *inflammable*, can I smoke near it? This phenomenon is known as a *contranym* and gets a lot of press in popular discussions about English. Maybe it happens in other languages too. Don’t know.

Comment: @DanBron: About inflammable - "in" is not necessary a negating prefix. About raze or cleave - not quite sure what you mean. But thanks for naming the general phenomenon.

Comment: *Cleave* means *tear apart* as well as *bind together*. The world *inflammable* can mean *combustible* or *not combustible*.  There is no "why" to natural languages, or, rather, asking "why" is the wrong question.  A tree has just so many branches, no more, no less. Asking "why" is, in some sense, meaningless. So it is for the growth and pruning of natural languages.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of the prefix “un” which can be  both  reversive or intensitive,   and yes, in the sense on untangle they have the same meaning:

> [Ravel](https://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/122929.html) probably comes from the Dutch word ravelen, meaning to 'fray out, tangle', and was first used in late Middle English with the sense of 'entangle, confuse'. ***Interestingly, the more commonly used verb definitions of ravel in Modern English actually have the opposite meaning: 'untangle', for example 'ravel something out'; and 'unravel; fray***, as in a 'ravelled collar' (the latter not in American usage). It's only the third verb definition, 'confuse or complicate', and the noun meaning, 'a tangle, cluster, knot', that are closer to the original meaning

[Unravel](https://www.etymonline.com/word/unravel):

> c. 1600 (transitive), from un- (2) + ravel (v.). Intransitive from 1640s. "***The prefix is either reversive or intensive, according as ravel is taken to mean 'tangle' or 'untangle'" [Century Dictionary].*** (Etymonline)
>
> Unravel,  is a verb which means to either 'undo', for example twisted threads, or to 'investigate and solve or explain' something which is complex or puzzling. A couple of examples of using unravel are:

(fandom-grammar)

Comment: So it seems that originally *ravel* meant to *tangle*, and *unravel* meant to *untangle*.  I think *un-* is reversive here. Can you name any other intensive uses of *un-*?